SMA connector, PCB, straight, with differential signal
Good evening,
I am designing a PCB that features a dipole antenna, of the same type we see on routers and about 6cm long (lambda/2 of 2.4GHz). In particular it is a rubber dipole whose interior looks like this .
The antenna is mounted on the PCB via a straight SMA connector (like in the picture)

The signal that goes to the antenna via the SMA connector comes from an AD8341, which outputs a differential signal.
The question is:
after I connected one differential signal to the center pin, should I connect the other differential signal to all the other 4 lateral pins of the SMA connector, or just to the closest one?
My fear is that connecting the 4 pins among themselves (in daisy chain around the square) would increase the length of the trace, for that signal, of an amount that at 2.4GHz might induce a significant phase shift.
Am I overthinking it?
Thanks!

you are overthinking it ... the four pins are all shorted together ... there is no daisychaining possible ...  the signal will go to the nearest pin

If you are using the differential output of the AD8341, put a 1:1 current balun in (or a LC-balun for narrowband application) to get a 50 Ohm single ended output for the SMA connector.

Sma is single ended connector and it is ment for single ended connections.
You could use it for a short, lower frequency also in a differential mode if you don't have need for a ground.
I would use 2x sma if possible, use the ground for connect between tx and your antenna for both signals, then i would use a balun. This is the proper way.
What you are asking is some sort of simplification. If you are going down this road, put antenna structure on the connector itself, meaning the antenna has to start when pins from SMA come to the pcb. And yes, use only one (would be) ground pin on SMA.
Don't connect all of them and by no means you should be connecting any traces between the connector and antenna. These would not act as transmission lines, sine for transmission lines in rf you need ground, which is not present on your antenna board as you chose to use only one sma.
Also, coax cable itself might cause issues because again, it's not proper rf transmission coax, it coax used in some differential way. It might cause issues, but if it will be short it should be fine.
Again, reconsider using 2x sma to bring differential signal to antenna board.
You can use a balun there or you can just connect the both diff lines to antenna ends, but at least you can make rf transmission lines on antenna board and use coax as it was intended.

Thanks a lot for the answer, I just would like to make clear one thing: the AD8341 is on the same PCB with the SMA connector, and aside from the pullup network (and the balun you're recommending) there would be just two traces between the chip and the connector. So, if I understand correctly the problem is that doesn't matter if the AD8341 output and the dipole are respectively a differential output and input: the sole fact that for the connection I am using a SMA connector (which is inherently single-ended) dooms me to make the output single-ended and therefore lose some power. Am I correct?

If yes, my next question would be, is there any connector other than the SMA that would allow me to keep the differential nature of the AD8341 output and pass it directly to the dipole?

They are called (micro) twinax connectors.
But I would suggest 2x SMA or 2x SMP. easy to use and cheap. put them close to each other on the board and use the centre pins for differential conenction.

To answer your first question, yes you are correct. The SMA is by design single ended. You can use it in a way that outer connection is not ground, but instead one of differential signals, however it can happen that this will create issues, since the coat of coax cable is meant for grounding.
The other issue is that by doing this you can't connect ground to the antenna board (you need "good" ground for RF), so you can't really use RF structures other than antenna on the antenna board, meaning also NO proper RF transfer lines. If you use 2x sma ground and both signals will be connected.

thanks again for the answer; you were probably picturing a long dipole antenna with its own cable, actually I will use a short dipole such as https://static.ticimax.cloud/cdn-cgi/image/width=-,quality=85/13353/uploads/urunresimleri/buyuk/kompent2.4-ghz-sma-anten-e90-9a.jpg, so the amount of coax cable that separates the SMA connector from the dipole itself is ~6cm (https://martybugs.net/wireless/images/ducky_inside_tn.jpg). Would this additional detail affect your answer? I'll update the initial post with these pictures.

also, if I double down on the SMA, how would I connect that dipole? Would I have to find another model of dipole that has a double SMA or SMP input?

I'll try to answer myself: the body of the SMA connector and the section of the dipole antenna before the actual antenna starts, make a coaxial (therefore single-ended) connection segment between the two differential devices (AD8341 on one side and the dipole on the other). This segment may be irrelevant at low frequencies, i.e. when the wavelength of the signal is much larger than the length of the coaxial segment, but in this case, at 2.4GHz, the wavelength is 12.5cm and the length of the SMA connector is, at best, 1cm, so it's kind of a risky gamble.
